# Why is WCF Workflow Service behave as one-way

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation

I am creating a WCF WorkflowService and the client is making an async call to the service. The workflow is quite long running, once the client disconnects the connection (i.e. closes the application the request was made from), the workflow continues and doesn't stop. How does this work? Once the cleint disconnect, doesn't the service instance gets destroyed, and the workflow should stop?

Why is it by default behaving as "fire and forget", i.e. one-way?

Edit: Well, i thought, once the client gets disconnected, the service instance is destroyed, and the workflow aborts

Comment: What behavior would you expect/prefer instead?

Comment: Well, i think, once the client gets disconnected, the service instance is destroyed, and the workflow aborts

Comment: This question only asks *why*. Will you be satisfied with a strictly  explanatory answer?

Comment: So do you want the workflow to be aborted, or the client to wait the completion? What if it will take hours?

Comment: NO, actually this is what I wanted, i.e. the client disconnects and it should keep on running. But i didn't thought this is by default. Wanted to understand, how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workflow engine models long-running asynchronous processes. Such processes can span second, hours, weeks and even years and may involve one or many participants. It is therefore unreasonable and undesirable to require a connection to be kept open.

A Windows Workflow Service saves its state to some data store, usually a database, so that if nothing happens in that workflow for a specified amount of time, it can be saved to the database and unloaded from memory. In the future, when someone calls one of the WCF operations related to that workflow instance, it is revived from the database and execution continues as if it was always loaded in memory. This allows a great many workflow instances to exist at any single point in time where only a small part of them are actually taking up computer resources.

Durability is also an important feature of a workflow service. If there is a workflow that has been going on for a long time, the last thing you want is all its state and data to be lost and that, if at all possible, you'll need to start it all over again. This is why the state information of a workflow does not rely on something as fragile as a network connection.

Comment: So, basically what I want is, the client makes a WCF call to invoke the workflow, and exits the application. The invoked workflow, would start and run asynchronously, and complete in its own time. I don't need to introduce message queue for something like this?

Comment: @Bhaskar: What do you mean by "run"? Usually a workflow spends most of its lifetime waiting for WCF calls, and doing a small bit of work when a call comes in or a timer elapses, etc. Can you describe what you want to achieve with WF? Can a simple non-WF OneWay WCF call suffice?

Comment: I have just one call, the user calls the ReceiveRequest method, and the workflow is started. The workflow doesn't need any user intervention after that. It performs a set of time consuming steps (e.g. huge file copy) which might span to hours. In the meantime the users needs to get out of the application and do something else. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Sound more suited as a WCF OneWay service than a Windows Workflow service. There is nothing "workflow"-ish in what you need to accomplish, you will use exactly zero features from WF. You're better off with plain old OneWay WCF service with a long or infinite timeout.